# are ad unit id and ppublisher id same?

Tags: android

I am new to  android applications dev . I am preparing an application which should display Admob at the bottom, for that i crated an ac in Admob and got a **publisher id** and placed in my code.

But client gave me integration details as

adunit ID -

> xxxx (five digit number)

Here is the app ID:

> 0axxxxxb-xxdx-xxxa-xxxx-cxxbxxxxxaxx (here x's are numbers)

my question is, are both adunit id and publisher id same? If so I have publisher id with 15 dig number...but adunit id is only 5 dig what should i do now?

Comment: Why don't you ask admob?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would say it's the same thing based on the [official Admob's documentations](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html)

> The five lines of code it takes to add
> a banner:
>
> - Import com.google.ads.*
> - Declare an AdView instance
> - Create it, specifying **a unit ID—your AdMob publisher ID**
> - Add the view to the UI
> - Load it with an ad

Clarify with your client.

Comment: So every ad in all of my apps should have the same id?

Answer (score 0):

No, PublisherId is unique account id whereas ad Unit id is id per application.

Answer (score 0):

I get the `adUnitId` using this method running from the `onCreate()` method from my app.

```
public void getIdThread() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {         
        @Override
        public void run() {
    // Do not call this function from the main thread. Otherwise, 
    // an IllegalStateException will be thrown.
    Info adInfo = null;
    try {
        adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(getApplicationContext());
        Log.d("AD_INFO", "adInfo :: " +adInfo);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Unrecoverable error connecting to Google Play services (e.g.,
        // the old version of the service doesn't support getting AdvertisingId).

    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // Google Play services is not available entirely.
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final String adUnitId = adInfo.getId();
    final boolean isLAT = adInfo.isLimitAdTrackingEnabled();
    Log.d("AD_INFO", "adUnitId :: " +adUnitId);
    Log.d("AD_INFO", "isLAT :: " +isLAT);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

and this is the format of an `adUnitId`:

```
da123eb7-19a9-43aa-a98b-9ae24de45f25
```

Comment: So every ad in all of my apps should have the same id?